# Swipe Cell in UICollectionView - Swift

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, nsindexpath

Is there an elegant and short way to progrematiclly swipe between two cells (assuming we have the desired NSIndexPath of the two cells)?

Comment: What do you mean by swipe? In case of collection view, I think of collection of many objects not just 2. Maybe you looking for or talking about UIScrollView? Describe your layout a little more.

Comment: I mean to replace one cell with another cell, just changing one cell position to another cell position and vice verse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see few possibilities here, having the information you provide.

1) You can use standard UICollectionView method: `- moveItemAtIndexPath:toIndexPath:`, but you must update your data source first.  For example, assume you already updated data source (note that this example code is useless until you figure out index changes after moving items.):

```
collectionView.performBatchUpdates({ () -> Void in
   collectionView.moveItemAtIndexPath(firstIndexPath,toIndexPath:secondIndexPath)
   //note: proper indexes might be changed after moveItem.. method. Play with it and you'll find the proper one for your item.
   collectionView.moveItemAtIndexPath(secondIndexPath,toIndexPath:firstIndexPath)        
}, completion: { (finish) -> Void in

})
```

2) You can recalculate your layout if you use custom layout

3) You can just reload collection view with `reloadData` or `reloadItemsAtIndexPaths`  E.g.:

```
 var dataSourceArray = [1,2,3,4,5]
 // some event occurred -> dataSourceArray changed
 dataSourceArray = [1,2,5,4,3]
 // call collectionView.reloadData() or reloadItemsAtIndexPaths(_:).
```

If you'll use 1st or 3rd way, in both cases data source must be up to date.